# ASP.NET Core Identity. Using ApplicationDbContext and UserManager. Do they share the context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

i have an database initialization method in an ASP.NET MVC Core 2 application.
In that method i'm using ApplicationDbContext and UserManager to initialize the database. 
I get both instances from the constructor's dependency injection:

```
public static void Initialize(ApplicationDbContext context,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> user)
```

What i want to know is if they share the same context instance or if one context is created for ApplicationDbContext and another for UserManager.
If i execute something like this:

```
ApplicationUser adminTeacherUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "test@test.com",
                Email = "test@test.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                Name = "test",
                LastName = "test",
                BirthDate = null,
                EntryDate = DateTime.Now                    
            };

            userManager.CreateAsync(adminTeacherUser, "password").Wait();
```

The user is created at database inmediatly after the CreateAsync call.

But, if then i update the user like this:

```
adminTeacherUser.Name = "other";                
userManager.UpdateAsync(adminTeacherUser);
```

After the call to UpdateAsync nothing is updated at the database. The name of the user stills being "test".

But, if then i execute:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

The changes are applied and the database is updated.

So, why the CreateAsync method "saves its changes" without explicitly calling "context.SaveChanges" and the UpdateAsync method needs it? Is the ApplicationDbContext instance i get by dependency injection the same that CreateAsync is using?

Thank you.

Comment: They use the same context for the scope of the request.

Comment: Also do not make blocking calls `.Wait()`, use `await` in an async method or risk deadlocks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default registration of Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET Core application is a per-request scope, so they will definitively share the context.

As you can see from the source code of the default implementation of EF Core for ASP.NET Core Identity ([here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/EF/UserStore.cs#L189)

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the specified <paramref name="user"/> in the user store.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">The user to create.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> used to propagate notifications that the operation should be canceled.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation, containing the <see cref="IdentityResult"/> of the creation operation.</returns>
public async override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }
    Context.Add(user);
    await SaveChanges(cancellationToken);
    return IdentityResult.Success;
}
```

and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/EF/UserStore.cs#L165)

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the specified <paramref name="user"/> in the user store.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">The user to update.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> used to propagate notifications that the operation should be canceled.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation, containing the <see cref="IdentityResult"/> of the update operation.</returns>
public async override Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }

    Context.Attach(user);
    user.ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Context.Update(user);
    try
    {
        await SaveChanges(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.ConcurrencyFailure());
    }
    return IdentityResult.Success;
}
```

, they both save changes.

The problem you are experiencing is that you are not `await`ing for the result of `UpdateAsync`, so you need to change to:

```
await userManager.UpdateAsync(adminTeacherUser);
//or
userManager.UpdateAsync(adminTeacherUser).Wait();
```

Of course, using *async-all-the-way* is the preferred version and you shouldn't block using `.Wait()`.

Comment: I would quicker suggest not using that blocking call altogether.

Comment: Even if he didn't `await` the call to `UpdateAsync`, shouldn't it save the changes to database? The code would just not wait until the save command was completed, but I believe it should save.

Comment: @Alisson That depends entirely on what happens after the call to `UpdateAsync`. If the requests ends right there, the context will be probably discarded before it had the chance to save the changes

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using .Wait() calls because that is a DB Initializer method, done as an extension of WebHost that is call from Program.Main; so no await is available here. In any case, that is development code mainly for testing.

Comment: @MorgoZ it's preferred to use `Task.Run(async () => await userManager.UpdateAsync(adminTeacherUser)).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in that case, rather than just calling `Wait()`.

Comment: @MorgoZ I figured that was the case, you can keep the `Wait()` there. Just don't do that on production code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that makes sense, I didn't consider the possiblity of the context being disposed, since it's scoped by request. Thanks for your reply!