# Using Identity's Managers in IdentityDbContext that was created by UseInMemoryDatabase()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I made this method to make unit testing `DbContext` much easier. This method makes `Context` of my `db` in memory. It works because i testing it with entities (like `_context.Projects`, `_context.Tests` etc., in unit testing, this method works):

```
        public static TaskManagerDbContext Create()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TaskManagerDbContext>()
                                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                                .Options;

            var context = new TaskManagerDbContext(options);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return context;
        }
```

My `DbContextClass` looks like this:

```
    public class TaskManagerDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ITaskManagerDbContext
    {
        public TaskManagerDbContext(DbContextOptions<TaskManagerDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        //db sets here

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(TaskManagerDbContext).Assembly);
        }
    }
```

My question is, can we make Identity's `UserManager`, `SignInManager`, `RoleManager` in memory, like we can do with `IdentityDbContext`? How to unit test `Identity` things like users, roles in memory like we can do with standard `Context`? How to call this `Managers` in fake context that is stored in memory while im testing it?

**EDIT:**

Based on [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519780/asp-net-core-identity-using-applicationdbcontext-and-usermanager-do-they-share) Identity shares `context` that is obvious. But how to use `Managers` on created `IdentityDbContext` by `UseInMemoryDatabase()` method?

**EDIT2:**

Im injecting `context` by fixture:

```
public class DatabaseFixture
{
    public TaskManagerDbContext Context { get; private set; }

    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        this.Context = DatabaseContextFactory.Create();
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition("DatabaseTestCollection")]
public class QueryCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
}
```

And usage of it:

```
[Collection("DatabaseTestCollection")]
public class RegisterUserCommandTests
{
    private readonly TaskManagerDbContext _context;

    public RegisterUserCommandTests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
    {
        _context = fixture.Create();
    }

    //and usage of it in class:
    var user = _context.Projects.Find(8);
}
```

Im using `Xunit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a service collection, register everything with that, and then use that to pull out what you need.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddDbContext<TaskManagerDbContext>(o =>
    o.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid()));
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TaskManagerDbContext>();
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then, you can use `provider`:

```
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
}
```

Comment: So, i will able to work on my `InMemory` database with corelated `Managers` with it? Can i do it in my `Fixture` class?

Comment: Yes and yes. You just need to pay attention to the scoping. You'll only be working with the same context with your managers if everything is within the same scope. You also can't just persist things like your context on fixture, for this reason. Instead, expose `provider` and then wrap your test in the a `CreateScope` using as I've done above.

Comment: I belive your answer works. if i will have problem, i will coment here

Comment: Do i need to using `using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())` in every test method? If not, could you tell me how to, for example, mock users in this scope to use it in all tests `class`?

Comment: Yes, at least in so far as you need these scoped services. For a "shared" user, store the primitive, then actually add to the context as part of each test. You'd pretty much need to do that anyways, as you wouldn't want test data to bleed between tests.